# How to call multiple subscribe in a loop

Tags: angular7

This is my code:

```
executeService(): void {
  var node = this.node;
  while(node.val != 0){
    this.httpClientService.executeService(node).
    subscribe( data => {
      alert("Run successfully");
      this.output = data; // getting value in this.output
      // Service call to update table.
    });
    node = node.childNode;
    node.prevOutput = this.output; // not getting output
  }
}
```

I am not able get output value outside of the subscribe closure.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your Node data structure but you may use recursive call:

```
executeService():void{
  recursiveServiceCall(this.node);
}

 recursiveServiceCall(node:any){

  this.httpClientService.executeService(node).
   subscribe( data => {
      node.prevOutput=data;
      if(node.childNode && node.val !=0)
         recursiveServiceCall(node.childNode);
      });
  }
```